# Why is there no overload of bool std::operator==(T1* a, std::shared_ptr<T2> b)?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, shared-ptr

I noticed that the stdlib doesn't provide an overload for the equality operator for a `shared_ptr` and a raw pointer. This especially unhandy if, say, you have a `std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` and you want to erase elements by passing a raw `Foo*`

Is there any specific reason that there is no such overload? As I see it, it is easy to implement:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool operator==(const T1 * a, const std::shared_ptr<T2> & b) {
    return a == b.get();
}
```

...would there by anything dangerous or unexpected with this implementation?

Comment: My memory of the spec is poor, but I believe there are some caveats around  pointers of different types. Any reason why this shouldn't be `operator==(const T * a, const std::shared_ptr<T> & b)`?

Comment: I think the OP wants to compare two pointers regardless of type, just to see if the raw memory location matches what's in the shared pointer. In a sense, it'd be like having a pointer to an int and a pointer to a float and casting them both to void * to see if they're the same thing. Not sure why anyone would want to take such an approach.

Comment: Actually, no, I don't intend to compare arbitrary pointers. This won't even compile, if T1 and T2 aren't of the same inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `unordered_set` you need more than just `==`, you also need `hash` to work.

For `set`, a transparent comparator lets you look things up by things that are not the key type.  `set` is not transparent by default, so that operator would do no good.

Once you add your own comparator, you can override `==` for it.

Sadly, `unordered_set` does not have a transparent option at this point in time.  In order to find/erase/etc something in an `unordered_set`, you **must** have the key type.

Your overload is questionable.  A better one is:

```
template<class U, class...Ts>
auto operator==( U const* lhs, std::shared_ptr<Ts...> const& rhs )->decltype( lhs == rhs.get() ) {
  return lhs == rhs.get();
}
template<class U, class...Ts>
auto operator==( std::shared_ptr<Ts...> const& lhs, U const* rhs )->decltype( lhs.get() == rhs ) {
  return lhs.get() == rhs;
}
```

but note that writing the above reasonably requires C++11 support.  A solution short of the above ends up being either a mess to write (with SFINAE), or claiming that there is a `==` between types there is not (and failing too late for other SFINAE code to realize it).

But what about `<`?  Well, `<` on raw pointers is only a good idea within the same object, so exposing it between shared pointers and raw pointers seems like a horrid idea.  So now we are approaching `std::less` and wanting to augment it with transparent support between smart pointers and non-smart pointers.

Do we also support mixing smart pointers (a `shared` and `unique`?) -- naively, you might say no, but a `unique_ptr` does not have to represent memory ownership if you replace the deleter!  (the same is true of a `shared_ptr`).  Should smart pointers with different deleters be considered equal or equivalent?  The meaning of the data may be very different based on the deleter.

Now, given that I have managed to come up with thorny questions from just a few minutes of work, **and** such an overload would encourage mixing of raw pointers and `shared_ptr`, **and** it doesn't even help solve the problem you wanted to solve with it, maybe it isn't a good idea.

Or maybe it is.  Which leads to the real reason why it isn't in the standard.

Nobody proposed it and got it accepted.

If you think it is a good idea, I encourage you to look into the proposal process.  Examine other proposals, figure out the right steps, and throw a proposal together.

If that seems too intimidating, you might want to create a robust library that provides said comparison operators, and get it into boost, and mayhap people will use it and say "wow, we always needed that!"

Comment: If you have `std::shared_ptr`, you have C++11, so that's not an unreasonable restriction. Still a good analysis. +1

Comment: @msalters true, except shared ptr was in tr's and mostly in boost: in both cases retrun type deduction based sfinae was not around until recently.

Comment: `shared_ptr` isn't templated on its deleter's type.

Comment: @t.c. point.  Left it `Ts...` for theoretical future expansion (which I doubt will occur).  Had unique on the brain.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with a shared_ptr, it's very dangerous to pass around raw pointers, since if you have something holding that raw pointer, it by definition breaks the shared_ptr concept of reference counts. The reason there's no overload is probably to discourage this.

Comment: `shared_ptr::get()` exists, though. A non-owning pointer is fine as long as its lifetime is known to be less than that of at least one `shared_ptr`.

Comment: That's true, but I think the implication of the post is that it couldn't be guaranteed that the raw pointer will have a shorter lifetime. Usually when one uses get() with a shared_ptr they're doing mundane things like memcopies.

Comment: @AlanStokes The existence of `shared_ptr::get()` is no contradiction to what stix said: The use of raw pointers is **discouraged**, not made **impossible**. It's an important distinction when you design an API: Don't allow potentially dangerous things implicitly/silently, make them explicit. That way the user of an API acknowledges that he actually intends to do something and that it is not just an accident.

Comment: @AlanStokes besides, IIRC the implementation may allocate the `T` object pointed-to by `shared_ptr::get()` along with the reference counter and other housekeeping materials; the result would be that if you mistreat the memory pointed-to by `get` (like `delete`-ing it or something), you may (or may not, or may sometimes) get catastrophic results.